# Can't Install Linux* open-iSCSI Initiator

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, openssl, iscsi

I'm trying to install this version the [open-iSCSI Initiator](https://github.com/open-iscsi/open-iscsi), however when I use the `make` command, it doesn't find the `openssl/evp.h` file, but I have the `openssl` package installed, so I don't get it. What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That file isn't part of the `openssl` package. It's provided by `libssl-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

It's common in Ubuntu and similar Linux distributions for applications and development libraries/headers to be in different packages. (If you're just going to be using the `ssh` command or running an ssh server, you don't need the header files.)

Comment: Thank you! Since the header file is `openssl/evp.h`, I was pretty sure it was included in the openssl package!